# Jquery вывод на печать

Tags: javascript, jquery, печать

Как оптимальнее всего определенный содержимое дива вывести на печать, чтобы кроме него ничего не было на странице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Также можно использовать CSS-правило [[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media) с указанием типа print, для обнуления стилей и скрытия ненужных при печати элементов.

```
@media print {
    * {
        color: #000 !important;
        background: transparent !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Скажем так, с помощью @media print переписать стили для дива так, чтобы он был поверх всего контента сайта и имел непрозрачный белый фон. Тогда при выводе на печать, будет виден только этот див.